# How do I make recursive named_scope calls on a Ruby class in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have defined a bunch of named_scopes in a rails Person model.  For example:

```
named_scope :male ...
named_scope :tall
named_scope :short
named_scope :happy
```

...whatever.

Well, what I'm doing is globbing a bunch of scopes in routes.rb and eventually I have an array of scopes...like this:

```
scopes = ["male", "happy", "short"]
```

Now, I know I can do this:

`Person.male.happy.short` and get the records that fit those scopes.

But I want to be able to do it via the array as a parameter, because as we know we can also do this:

```
somescope = "male"
result = Person.send(somescope)
```

which is the same as

```
result = Person.male
```

So given an array of scopes, like the "scopes" one above, how can I best get the result

```
Person.male.happy.short
```

from the array

```
["male", "happy", "short"]
```

?

mucho appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@people = ["male", "happy", "short"].inject(Person) { |person, scope| person.send(scope) }
```